# Case sensitive in regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I´m new to regular expressions, I need find one phrase in a piece of text (case insensitive), for example:

Text :  FindThis("This is example text")

I need get "FindThis" to locate my phrase regardless of the case of the text.

I've tried this:

```
static Regex text= new Regex("(FindThis\\(['|\"])([^'\"]*)");
```

Comment: By default a `Regex` is done in a case sensitive manner.  Can you try and explain what is going wrong by providing samples that you expect should match and don't?

Comment: Experiment. Sites like rubular.com are awesome for this. Regexes are, indeed, case sensitive by default (unless you add the `i` flag at the end).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, and I understand, the regular expression is case sensitive by default, but, in my example if I change the example test for "FiNdThIs("This is example text")" is not mached, I´m explain?

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like it to be matched regardless of case?

Comment: I say that in my example when I change one letter per upper or lower case, the regular expression stops working (in my example)

Comment: I'll edit your question to make that clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase enum. Here's an example:

```
var result = Regex.IsMatch("Here's some FINDTHIS Text", // the text to search in
                "FindThis", // this is the text we're looking for
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // specifies that it's not case sensitive
```

Note that in this case our regex pattern is actually just the text we're looking for. It could equally be a much more complex pattern.

I would check that the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method doesn't do what you're looking for? It's a lot simpler!

Comment: was not what I was looking for, but I used it anyway, thank you very much! (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 3):

Case sensitive should be "on" by default. You can pass the option to ignore case when you do the match.

Here's an example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex

Comment: Thanks for the response, but, in my example if I change the example test for "FiNdThIs("This is example text")" is not mached, I´m explain?

Comment: You'll need to post more code. You show the RegEx being created, but there should be a regEx.Match method with an input string. What's the rest of your code look like?

Comment: Don´t worry, I resolved this another way, anyway, thank you very much